# Filtering twitter data

Tags: twitter, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I have implemented an unsupervised algorithm for sentiment analysis on data from social media sites, specifically from Twitter.
However I intend to gauge what people are saying about a specific topic, say 'traffic in certain state' for example.
I could gather data using keywords such as 'traffic', 'congestion', pedestrians' and so on.
Some of this acquired data has different contexts and has nothing to do with traffic.
My questions are -
1. How do i filter out data based on topics?
2. Do i need to perform topic extraction or use spam filter?

Comment: If I understood properly, you've already downloaded tweets using those keywords and now you want to know which of those are really related to traffic? I guess [this](https://aritter.github.io/twitter_ner.pdf) could be a starting point. It's in my pile of things to study but I really haven't gone through it yet. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could something like [this](http://www.datumbox.com/machine-learning-api/) be helpful? They offer an API for analysing twitter sentiment based on context. Although, you may still run into the same issue with spam.

(Sorry it might not really be an answer but I'm unable to comment).

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting link. But i am looking to working it out by myself since the implementation is part of an academic project.